# How to make a Telerik radDataGrid Public

Tags: uwp, telerik, uwp-xaml

I have a Telerik RadDataGrid in a UWP app that I want to make public so I can see it and update it on another page when I change my datasource.

But I cannot find a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the same way as with any other XAML element: x:FieldModifier="public"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-fieldmodifier-attribute